# How to share data to one component to another component in context API with Router in react JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

Here I create two components. first is Login.jsx and another is User.jsx. I want to share data with User.jsx to Login.jsx with using Router. when the Client enters data in User.jsx then the enter code here client clicks on the Register button then the component Switch to Login.jsx and shows all the data in Login.jsx using Context API.

```
 <div className="user form">
       <h2>User</h2>
       <span>Username</span>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="uname" onChange={userForm} id="" />
       <span>Password</span>
       <input type="password" name="pwd" id="" placeholder="Password" onChange={userForm} />
       <span>Confirm Password</span>
       <input type="password" name="cpwd" id="" placeholder="Confirm Password " onChange{userForm} />
       <Link to="/" ><button>Resigister</button></Link>
   </div>
   <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
                <Mycontext.Provider value={form}>
                    <Login />
                </Mycontext.Provider>
          </Route>
            <Route path="/a" component={Admin} />
        </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Correction on confirm password input `onChange={userForm}`
2. Save your form data in state and pass down data as props.